# The Prophet's last sermon : can anybody provide a link to the hadith source (English)?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I was trying to find a hadith source to the `last sermon of the Prophet`. Can anybody provide me with a source from `Bukhari or Muslim`, or any other of the 6 major hadith collections. **Kindly provide a source that can be viewed online**.

There are some references that mention the hadith number. Unfortunately, I can't find any online hadith portal that uses that system. They usually use 'book name followed by the hadith number inside the book' system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://www.iqrasense.com/about-islam/the-last-sermon-khutbah-of-prophet-muhammad-farewell-sermon.html) has the sermon referenced from Bukhari, Muslim and Tirmidhi.The exact location can be [found here](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/25/217), the sermon is probably spanned in multiple consecutive hadith.

Comment: I can't find the reference in any online translation of the hadith. Most of them have a book name and a hadith inside it. Any link that has reference system by direct hadith number ?

Comment: @Daud you can check it here :http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/25 also edited the answer for exact location